# Haar cascade training OpenCV on Mac OS X

Tags: android, macos, opencv, detection, haar-classifier

I am trying to develop a simply Android OpenCV program which can detect a black dot on white paper using a Samsung Galaxy S3 camera.

To do this I've just copied the face detection program from OpenCV samples and I want to add my own Haar cascades to search for dots instead of faces. I have been sitting here for something like two days, and I can't find anything useful - everything is made on Windows or Linux.

Can anyone tell me a tip how to make my own XML with Haar cascade on the Mac or is there any other (easier) way to implement that?

Comment: There is a mac version of opencv, so it should be possible as it is possible on other platforms like linux...

Comment: you cannot train a cascade classifier on *dots* (you need a certain level of detail). forget that.

Comment: so what should i choose? jni + hough cirlces? or is there any example in java for android?

Answer (score 0):

Open CV for ANDROID:  http://opencv.org/platforms/android.html

Open CV provides a built in example for Shape Detection for windows and linux(don't know if its available on android). Its your duty to search for it. A slight modification can help you with your task.

haar-classifiers are mainly meant for dealing with human body, face, etc. Although you can train and create your own haar classifiers for this task(http://note.sonots.com/SciSoftware/haartraining.html#t1a1f262) but its like madness because there are other so easy methods out there.

Comment: thanks for your coment. I need to do pupil detector but im actually not sure which method i should use. i was thinking about blob detection. I need to "put" my application on hardkernel odroid-xu3. I have build helmet with camera looking on my eyes. Im not sure which programming lang i should use too. Professor from my colege told me to use c# with egnu. what you think about it?

Comment: @kolorszczak I would suggest C++ and Open CV to ooze out maximum real time performance from it.EMGU CV is just a wrapper on OPEN CV for using the functions inside the open cv dll files, So most of the functions will be similar to open cv. The board also supports Linux. You can use a light weight Linux distro and C++ because it has lot of community support, so programming can be faster